# PHP GD - crop image around any given point

Tags: php, gd, center, crop

I have the following script that successfully crops and image at the center point using php's gd:

```
list($source_width, $source_height, $source_type) = getimagesize($img_path);

define('IMAGE_WIDTH', 200);
define('IMAGE_HEIGHT', 300);

$ratio = $source_width / $source_height;
$desired_aspect_ratio = IMAGE_WIDTH / IMAGE_HEIGHT;

if ($ratio > $desired_aspect_ratio) {
    $temp_height = IMAGE_HEIGHT;
    $temp_width = ( int ) (IMAGE_HEIGHT * $ratio);
} else {
    $temp_width = IMAGE_WIDTH;
    $temp_height = ( int ) (IMAGE_WIDTH / $ratio);
}

$x = ($temp_width - IMAGE_WIDTH) / 2;
$y = ($temp_height - IMAGE_HEIGHT) / 2;

$cropped = imagecreatetruecolor(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT);
imagecopy(
    $cropped,
    $temp,
    0, 0,
    $x, $y,
    IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT
);
```

Instead of this for the center:

```
$x = ($temp_width - IMAGE_WIDTH) / 2;
$y = ($temp_height - IMAGE_HEIGHT) / 2;
```

on my site users can select the 'main focus' of the image, in which i will crop the image around that. The focus will be supplied as a percentage. I already have the percentage and a way for the customer to select this, i just need to then take these values and crop around them. Can this be done? For example if i wanted my image to be cropped around the point as in the diagram below:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how the PHP would be to crop around a selected point, or how to get the position form the user from which to crop?

Comment: how i can use PHP to crop around the point. I already have the stored positions ready to use

Comment: for the logic part you have to take the coordinates of the focus point, subtract 100 from it and use it as your x1/y1. For x2/y2 you do the same but instead of subtracting 100 you add it this time. That's the basic procedure. You still need to check for the image borders and other edge cases.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat thank you. I'm trying to write out the logic/formula but can't seem to get it right. I'm unsure what you mean by x1 and x2, y1 and y2?

Comment: expressed in other words: x1/y1 is the point where you start the cropping process and x2/y2 minus x1/y2 is the width/height you need to crop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below function should do what you want.

- passing only the first argument will output what you have now: the middle of the source image cropped to 200px/200px.
- the second and third arguments allow you to specify the X/Y percent coordinates for the centre of the crop, as you want.
- the fourth and fifth arguments allow you to set the size of the cropped image.

(Note that this assumes PNG, but you should be able to adapt it easily enough for other formats, if needed.)

```
function crop($file, $cropX = 50, $cropY = 50, $cropW = 200, $cropH = 200)
{
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($cropW, $cropH);

    list($src_w, $src_h) = getimagesize($file);

    // calculate x/y coordinates for crop from supplied percentages.
    $src_x = (($src_w / 100) * $cropX) - ($cropW / 2);
    $src_y = (($src_h / 100) * $cropY) - ($cropH / 2);

    imagecopy($dest, $src, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);

    imagedestroy($src);

    return $dest;
}
```

Example usage (setting the crop focus of X to 70%):

```
$img = crop('test.png', 70);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```